# TouchesMoved get label text only once

Tags: ios, uilabel, touch-event

I'm working on a classic game "find a word"
like this example looking for "lion"

G H K J L D F G F Y E

J L M N **L I O N** A D T

G F O I A F E A D G H
...

I have this code to get all the letter values

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:allLetters];
for (UILabel *letter in self.lettersArray) {


    if (touchPoint.x > letter.frame.origin.x &&
        touchPoint.x < letter.frame.origin.x + letter.frame.size.width &&
        touchPoint.y > letter.frame.origin.y &&
        touchPoint.y < letter.frame.origin.y + letter.frame.size.height )
    {

       [letter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        NSLog(@"%@",letter.text);



    }


}}
```

it works well because it correctly gets the labels text when I touch them with my finger. My problem is that I need to get the value only once...

Now it gets the value many many times until you pass to another letter

do you have any advice?

thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you have to save the last letter bounds, and check whether you are in the same rect or moved away.

First, declare a rect to store the current letter.

`CGRect lastLetter;`

Then modify your method as per below:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:allLetters];
for (UILabel *letter in self.lettersArray) {


    if (touchPoint.x > letter.frame.origin.x &&
        touchPoint.x < letter.frame.origin.x + letter.frame.size.width &&
        touchPoint.y > letter.frame.origin.y &&
        touchPoint.y < letter.frame.origin.y + letter.frame.size.height )
    {

       [letter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        if(letter.frame.origin.x != lastLetter.origin.x)
        {
             lastLetter = letter.frame;
             NSLog(@"%@",letter.text);
        }



    }


}}
```

Comment: wow! thank you dude! That's perfect... I just add the if statement also for the Y

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array that stores all touched labels, something like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   if(!_touchedLetters) // create the array if it doesn't exists
      _touchedLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

   CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:allLetters];
   for (UILabel *letter in self.lettersArray) {

    if([_touchedLetters containsObject:letter]) //continue if it already been added
        continue;

    if (touchPoint.x > letter.frame.origin.x &&
        touchPoint.x < letter.frame.origin.x + letter.frame.size.width &&
        touchPoint.y > letter.frame.origin.y &&
        touchPoint.y < letter.frame.origin.y + letter.frame.size.height )
    {

       [letter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        NSLog(@"%@",letter.text);

       [_touchedLetters addObject:letter]
    }
}}
```

Then you could empty the array in - (void)touchesEnded:withEvent: